# How to stabilize voltage when controlling 12V motor

Tags: motor, dc-motor, oscillation

I have 12V bus which is connected to motor via polarity changing MOSFET configuration (see image), also I have connected to 12V NE555P and CD4041UB. Problem is when I am switching motor, on my 12V bus occurs up to 23V (see image). It is short oscillation but I have no experience if NE555P with 18V absolute max. ratings and CD4041UB with 20V absolute max. ratings can handle it. Best practice would be certainly limit these oscillations, but they are very short and I am not sure how. Zener diode or op amp would not be fast enough I guess. Should i use coil? If yes with what value?

[image: MOSFET driver]
[image: oscillation]

Comment: Start with decoupling capacitors. (And yes, overvolt pulses can destroy ICs)

Comment: since you have what seems to be a 4 channel scope, can you simultaneously show the input signals to the top and bottom of one side of the H bridge? Try looking at both pre-buffer and post-buffer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a couple of things here. First, you need to add diodes on each side of the motor and connect them to power terminals like this image from [here](https://www.pinterest.com/pin/399835273141263326/) (I recommend not to use the MOSFET internal diodes):

[image: DC Motor driver]

Also, add the capacitor like the image near the power terminal. The Zener is also a good idea. If the speed of Zener is not good enough, use a faster diode like TVS diodes (I doubt you be needing that).

NOTE: in the circuit in the picture, the protecting diodes (D1, D2, D3, D4) are connected directly to the power terminal. You are using a resistor to detect current consumption; so notice that the diode must be connected to the ground, not the resistor.

Comment: I don't see why MOSFET intrinsic diodes may not be used. All industrial drivers use them.

Comment: I wanted to ask the same, I don't want further increase size of my PCB if possible.

Comment: There are a couple of reasons. But it's more of a suggestion (I change the response to be clear that it's a suggestion). The first reason would be that you are using a resistor for the current sense. So, you have to use a diode to connect the sides of the motor to the ground (to avoid voltage rise). Second, notice that if you use a PWM signal, in off cycles, the power will be dissipated in diodes. So if you are using the intrinsic diode, it will be dissipated in MOSFET; because of that, you will be needing a bigger MOSFET.

Comment: With discrete diodes, you can also use schottky diodes. Benefit is lower forward voltage in the diodes (less dissipation in them, they can be smaller), and faster reverse recovery. It's an option in case you decide to push larger/faster currents than typical for a driver chip that you already know well, have programmed etc. If application is not trying to squeeze out max performance from the driver, I also feel it is not necessary.

Comment: PS 1N4001 is a relatively slow diode for this purpose